# WordPress - проблема с меню

Tags: wordpress, меню

В выпадающем меню WordPress если активный родительский пункт, то один из дочерних пунктов стает некликабельным. Встречал такое уже на нескольких сайтах на WP. В чем может быть причина. Для примера можно посмотреть сайт http://www.giottoclub.ru/menu/
При активном пункте Меню, его подпункт "Паста и Ризотто" стает некликабельным.

UPD. Изменил данный пункт - сделал его произвольной ссылкой и вставил ссылку на нужную категорию. Но хотелось бы на будущее все таки решить в чем проблема

Comment: Скорее всего, меню собиралось "вручную", т.е. добавлялись просто элементы без ссылки на страницу. Видимо, страница еще не создана. С точки зрения кода все ок

Comment: подпункт меню это категория произвольного типа поста, такой же как и остальные подпункты, но почему то не работает только он один. При чем родительский пункт не активен, то это подпункт отображается хорошо. Не работает именно при активной родительском пункте.

Comment: Изменил данный пункт - сделал его произвольной ссылкой и вставил ссылку на нужную категорию. Но хотелось бы на будущее все таки решить в чем проблема...